# How can I split datetime in sql

Tags: sql, database

I want to be able to split datetime in sql but specifically the time for example : 2015-02-27 10:13:12.733 
I want to be able to split date/time and then hours/minutes/seconds

I can't find anything on the net already that shows how to split the actual time don't even know if thats possible without getting into
a big complex solution so any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by split date time. Do you want the date part and time part separate from the datetime value ? Which DBMS you using ?

Comment: cast(column as date), extract(hour from column) etc. (ANSI SQL)

Comment: Which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

For SQL Server

```
 select CAST('2015-02-27 10:13:12.733' as DATE) -- Gives Date
 select DATEPART(HOUR,'2015-02-27 10:13:12.733')   --Gives  Hours
 select DATEPART(MINUTE,'2015-02-27 10:13:12.733')  --Gives  MINUTE
 select DATEPART(SECOND,'2015-02-27 10:13:12.733')  --Gives  SECOND
```

Answer (score 0):

**Database** : Oracle
**Function** : Extract

**Syntax** :

```
EXTRACT (
    { YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE | SECOND }
    | { TIMEZONE_HOUR | TIMEZONE_MINUTE }
    | { TIMEZONE_REGION | TIMEZONE_ABBR }
    FROM { date_value | interval_value } )
```

Details : For getting any specific field from the `Datetime` Column in Oracle, there is a Extract function available. The `Oracle EXTRACT(Date Time)` function splits a `datetime` or interval expression and returns the value of the specified `datetime` field

```
(YEAR, MONTH, DAY from DATE and TIMEZONE_HOUR, TIMEZONE_MINUTE from TIMEZONE).
```